# Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int

Tags: java, string, integer

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is get the item ID, and set a price from a ini, basically like: itemid:price
but, i cannot simply do item.getId().toString().
I'm trying to get item
What can I do to make it a string?

```
public static void getBuyPrice(Item item) {
    try {
        String itemId = item.getId().toString();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "./data/prices.ini")));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals(itemId)) {
                String[] split = line.split(":");
                item.getDefinitions().setValue(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

That is my code, (of course I have the error at item.getId().toString()), What can I do to convert that to a string?

Comment: String itemID = ""+item.getId();

Comment: Sorry this is not a full answer (because i have no enough privilege to comment) but did you write the toString() method for the ID in the Item class ? or just use Integer.toString(item.getId() if the ID is a primitive type.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Primitive types do not have methods, as they are not objects in Java. You should use the matching class:

```
Integer.toString(item.getId());
```

Answer (score 8):

```
String itemId = Integer.toString(item.getId());
```

Comment: Ah yes, why didnt I think of this first of all! Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: you beat me.

Answer (score 3):

```
String itemId = Integer.toString(item.getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Primitive types (int, double, byte etc..) can't have methods.
So use this :

```
String itemId = String.valueOf(item.getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Better:

```
String itemId = String.valueOf(item.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to just say `"" + myInt`, assuming myInt is assigned.

So try:

```
item.getDefinitions().setValue("" + Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
```

Of course, you may want to wrap the line in a try/catch in case there are parsing errors or split[1] is null, index out of range, etc.

Alternatively, the method `Integer.valueOf(str)` will return an Integer object (as opposed to a primitive) which will allow you to directly call the .toString() function.

```
item.getDefinitions().setValue(Integer.valueOf(split[1]).toString());
```

I particularly like .valueOf() because it caches many Integer objects.