# Cannot invoke equals(String) on the primitive type int error?

Tags: java

I am having problem with the `if statement block` below:

```
public void viewaccount ( ) {
    Scanner getinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your account number to log in");
    int login = getinput.nextInt();
    if (login.equals("accnumber")) {   // <== here
        /* to be written */
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, yes. You have an `int`. What do you expect calling `equals("accnumber")` on it will do? What are you trying to achieve? If you tell us your aim, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: You can't use the `.equals()` method invoked on a primitive type int. Your error message explains this. You most likely want to say `if ("accnumber".equals(login))` or, more generally:
`if (String.valueOf(login).equals("accnumber"))`

Comment: I want to see if it matches the accountnumber the users types in to an arraylist. Are there any suggestions for an alternative? @JonSkeet

Comment: @salman what arraylist? Please post the code you are actually going to use...

Comment: Well where is the ArrayList? You've only asked the user for a single value so far... Perhaps you want to see if some other ArrayList *contains* the value? Do you understand that `"accnumber"` is a string literal? Assuming you're taking a course, I think it may be worth asking your teacher for some more help - Stack Overflow is great for specific problems, but I think you need to revisit the basics before progressing further.

Comment: Alright I see now, I will give it a try, thanks.  @Kon

Comment: The array list "accnumber" is from the superclass which I am now using in the subclass. @JonSkeet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961892/cannot-invoke-tostring-on-the-primitive-type-int)

Comment: @salman: "accnumber" isn't a variable - it's a string literal. It's vital that you understand that.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was wondering where I recognized your name from and then  I noticed that you were the author of *C# in Depth*. Good to see such an informed and knowledgeable member helping users on this site. Anyway, back on topic. OP, in your code, you are seemingly checking if the user typed in the literal characters: "accnumber". (*Your code will not work to test this because you are using `.nextInt()` on your scanner, but barring that, this is what you are checking for.*) If you want to see if the account number entered is in an ArrayList, then use `.contains()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.equals(String)` is a method to check if two strings contain the same characters/text. Obviously, you cannot call `.equals()` on an int to check if it contains the same characters as a string, because an int does not contain characters (until it is converted to a human-readable form, of course).

If you want to check if the user entered the correct *account number*, you should do something like this:

```
public void viewaccount() {

    Scanner getinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your account number to log in");
    int login = getinput.nextInt();

    // Correct account number:
    int correctAccountNumber = 1234567;

    if (login == correctAccountNumber) {
        // Hooray! Success.


    }else{
        System.out.println("You have entered the incorrect account number.");
    }

}
```

*If this was ever used in a real-world application, then from a security perspective this would be a nightmare, but for learning, this should solve your problem.*

---

To give you a more indepth look at how `.equals()` works, I recommend reading up on [the Java `Objects` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). `int` is a [primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type), so it does not have methods built into it like `String` has. `String` is considered a [composite data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type) which allows `String` to have methods and attributes like `.length()`, `.equals()`, `.trim()`, etcetera.

In Java, all classes have `Object` as a superclass which allows all classes and composite data types to inherit methods like `.equals()`, `.hashcode()`, and `.toString()`, but on top of that, all composite data types can also implement their own methods. For example, the `Integer` data type (which is a wrapper for the primitive `int`) adds functions such as `.parseInt()` and `.compare()`.

Unlike most languages, Java provides primitive data types and built-in wrapper classes for all of those data types. `int` has `Integer`. `boolean` has `Boolean`. `long` has `Long`. `char` has `Character`. And the list goes on for all other primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method is a method of the class `Object`. Primitive types such as `int` are not objects and do not have access to the `equals` method.

When you want to compare primitive types you have to use `==`. In your case you are trying to compare an `int` (which is a number) with a `String` (which is a text) and this does not make sense - it will always be `false`

Maybe in your case you should read the input as a String like this:

```
String login = getinput.next();
```

Then you can use the `equals` method because the `login` variable will be of type `String` which extends `Object` and can be compared with `equals`.

**EDIT**:

If you still want to read data as a number, you should afterwards convert the login variable from int to String in order to compare it with another String.

This is done like this:

```
int login = getinput.nextInt();
    if (String.valueOf(login).equals("accnumber")) {   
        /* to be written */
    }
```

Ofcourse this would always return false, so this would work only if the `String` literal you give is something like "131423". I really hope that this "accnumber" is a dummy String that you use for the example only. Otherwise I dont see any other fine approach to this.

Comment: While this may solve the compile error, it is clearly not what the OP is intending to do (following the prompt to 'enter account number to login')

Comment: I will add some more explanation to my answer so that he can chose.

Comment: Sorry, but the edit is not useful at all - an `int` converted to `String` will _never_ equal the literal string "accnumber"

Comment: There is no alternative of approaches for the example - the OP either wants an int value and will compare it with something different from "accnumber" or he needs to read String data. I have given both suggestions an example approach so he can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare an int you don't need to use the .equals() method. Since you are casting the input to an int you can use "==" to compare one int to another. Also, "accnumber" needs to be an initialized as an int variable.

Answer (score -1):

Just grab the next string instead of the next int.

```
String input = getInput.next();
input.equals("accountNumber");
```

Comment: While this may solve the compile error, it is clearly not what the OP is intending to do (following the prompt to 'enter account number to login')

Comment: @Chris This is exactly what the op is trying to do. They want to compare a user inputted value to a known value. Why use an int over a String?

Comment: The user inputted value is an account number - ie: 12345. This will never equal the literal string "accountNumber"

Comment: @Chris Do you have any reason to believe the account number is an int? Of course "accountNumber" is not what they want to match finally, but why not match strings instead of int's? Maybe the account number has too many digits to be an int?